# Spring Server deleting automatically the files stored on the application Folder

Tags: java, spring-mvc, save, file-manager

I have a Spring Server which works as a boot application.

I use h2 Driver to save the different objects with JPA.
All this objects are updating OK.

I use this Class to manage all the Files that will be updated on the Server:

> ```
> public class LocalFileManager {
> /**
>  * This static factory method creates and returns a 
>  * ImageFileManager object to the caller. Feel free to customize
>  * this method to take parameters, etc. if you want.
>  * 
>  * @return
>  * @throws IOException
>  */
> public static LocalFileManager get() throws IOException {
>     return new LocalFileManager();
> }
> private Path targetDir_ = Paths.get("locals");
> // The ImageFileManager.get() method should be used
> // to obtain an instance
> private LocalFileManager() throws IOException{
>     if(!Files.exists(targetDir_)){
>         Files.createDirectories(targetDir_);
>     }
> }
> // Private helper method for resolving Image file paths
> private Path getLocalPath(Postosaude g, int PictureNumberByLocal){
>     assert(g != null);
>     return targetDir_.resolve("picture"+"-"+g.getId()+"-"+PictureNumberByLocal+".jpg");
> }
> /**
>  * This method returns true if the specified Image has binary
>  * data stored on the file system.
>  * 
>  * @param v
>  * @return
>  */
> public boolean hasLocalData(Postosaude g,int i){
>     Path source = getLocalPath(g, i);
>     return Files.exists(source);
> }
> /**
>  * This method copies the binary data for the given Image to
>  * the provided output stream. The caller is responsible for
>  * ensuring that the specified Image has binary data associated
>  * with it. If not, this method will throw a FileNotFoundException.
>  * 
>  * @param v 
>  * @param out
>  * @throws IOException 
>  */
> public void copyGiftData(Postosaude g,int i, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
>     Path source = getLocalPath(g,i);
>     if(!Files.exists(source)){
>         throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to find the referenced gift file for giftId:"+g.getId());
>     }
>     Files.copy(source, out);
> }
> /**
>  * This method reads all of the data in the provided InputStream and stores
>  * it on the file system. The data is associated with the Image object that
>  * is provided by the caller.
>  * 
>  * @param v
>  * @param ImageData
>  * @throws IOException
>  */
> public void saveLocalData(Postosaude g,int i, InputStream localData) throws IOException{
>     assert(localData != null);
>     Path target = getLocalPath(g,i);
>     Files.copy(localData, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
> }
> public void deleteImageFromLocal(Postosaude g, int i) throws IOException
> {
>     Path target = getLocalPath(g,i);
>     Files.delete(target);
> }
> ```
>
> }

This code is working perfectly. **It saves correctly all the Files**(images) that I update in the Folder `/locals/`, but if a restart the Server, **they are deleted automatically**.

This is the code from the Application class, maybe helps you to find out the mistake:

> ```
> @EntityScan(basePackages= "palmaslab.mapas.repository")
> @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= "palmaslab.mapas.repository"/*.PostoSaudeRepository.class*/)
> @Configuration
> @EnableAutoConfiguration
> @ComponentScan(basePackages="palmaslab.mapas.controller")
> @Import({palmaslab.mapas.security.SecurityConfiguration.class})
> @EnableWebMvc
> @PropertySource("application.properties")
> public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
> private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
>     "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
>     "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
>      }
>  @Bean
>     public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
>             DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
>         LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
>         lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
>         lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
>         lef.setPackagesToScan("palmaslab.mapas.controller");
>         return lef;
>     }
>     @Bean
>     public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
>         HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
>         hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
>         hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true); //Auto creating scheme when true
>         hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);//Database type
>         return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
>     }
>     @Bean 
>     public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() { 
>         SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
>         Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
>         dialects.add(new SpringSecurityDialect());
>         dialects.add(new LayoutDialect());
>         engine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);
>         LinkedHashSet<ITemplateResolver> templateResolvers = new LinkedHashSet<ITemplateResolver>(2);
>         templateResolvers.add(templateResolverServlet());
>         templateResolvers.add(layoutTemplateResolverServlet());
>         engine.setTemplateResolvers(templateResolvers);
>         return engine;
>     } 
>    @Bean 
>     public ServletContextTemplateResolver layoutTemplateResolverServlet() { 
>         ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
>         templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/layout/");
>         templateResolver.setSuffix("");
>         templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
>         templateResolver.setOrder(1);
>         templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
>         return templateResolver;
>     } 
>      @Bean 
>     public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolverServlet() { 
>         ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
>         templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
>         templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
>         templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
>         templateResolver.setOrder(2);
>         templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
>         return templateResolver;
>     } 
>    @Bean 
>      public ViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() { 
>         ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
>         resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
>         resolver.setOrder(1);
>         resolver.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
>         resolver.setCache(false);
>         return resolver;
>     }     
> @Bean
> public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration() {
>     ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet());
>     registration.addUrlMappings("/");
>     registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
>     return registration;
> }
> @Override
> public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
>     configurer.enable();
> }
> @Bean
> public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
>     return new DispatcherServlet();
> }
> @Bean
> public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
>     MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
>     factory.setMaxFileSize("999999KB");
>     factory.setMaxRequestSize("999999KB");
>     return factory.createMultipartConfig();
> }
>  @Bean
>   public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
>     CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
>     resolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000000);
>     return resolver;
>   }
> @Bean
> public CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
>     CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
>     resolver.setDefaultEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
>     resolver.setMaxUploadSize(500000000);
>     resolver.setMaxInMemorySize(500000000);
>     return resolver;
> }
> @Bean
> public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
>     TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
>     factory.setPort(8080);
>     factory.setSessionTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
>     //factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.404, "/notfound.html"));
>     return factory;
> }
> @Override
> public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
>     if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
>         registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations(
>                 "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
>     }
>     if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/locals/**")) {
>         registry.addResourceHandler("/locals/**").addResourceLocations(
>                  "classpath:/locals");
>       }
> }
> ```

Anyone can find my mistake?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create or modify files where the application is deployed then they will be deleted when you restart the server, because the application will be redeployed.

If you want the files to survive the redeploy, your storage base directory must be outside of the application folder (eg. `/srv/myapp/locals`).

Comment: Thank you for the information, do you know how i could save these files outside of the application folder using `Paths.get("")` ??

Comment: @AlbertoCrespo Well you can use `Paths.get()` to get some absolute path outside of your application on your system. For instance `Paths.get("/srv/myapp/locals")`. Btw: it would be even better to specify this path in some configuration file and load it from it when the application starts rather than to hardcode it in the source code.

Comment: how could I do that? It seems to have root permission.You know some example? Thank you

Comment: @AlbertoCrespo You can create property in your application.properties config file, eg. `storage.baseDir=/srv/myapp/locals` and then just inject that value using `@Value("${storage.baseDir}") String baseDir` in your code. But since the LocalFileManager doesn't appear to be Spring bean you would have to inject it elsewhere and pass it to it via constructor for instance. When you deploy your application to production, you would just override the default config using one of the methods described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: @AlbertoCrespo And regarding the root permission. You have to choose a directory to which your application has sufficient privileges to write. Or modify the directory permissions to make it accessible (ie using chown/chmod)

Comment: just need save files in /resource directory

Comment: I have same issue, but i recognised one thing if I'm putting file manually in target folder then it don't delete only uploaded files keep delete, what it means...